# how to get coordinates of a point on mouseclick from r graphplot

Tags: r, plot, time-series

I have plotted a graph in R. What should I do if I want the coordinates of the point of mouse click on the graph?

I searched a bit for this and understand that 'identify' function is being used for this but I didn't quite understand how to use it. Please give a detailed answer, this is my first time using R

script I used for plotting the graph:

```
data <- read.csv('C:\\project\\data.csv', header=T)
plot(data$time, data$param1, ylim=c(-1,1))
points(data$time, data$param2, col='red')
points(data$time, data$param3, col='green')
points(data$time, data$param4, col='blue')
```

the data is like:

```
time,param1,param2,param3,param4
1,-0.000963631,0.00340714,8.39E-05,0.999994
2,0.0841218,0.990477,0.0119087,0.108337
3,0.077221,0.995096,0.027441,0.0553834
4,0.0669772,0.996577,0.0441491,-0.0199725
5,0.0523895,0.989463,0.0645968,-0.118515
```

and the graph looks like:
[image]

The reason I'm doing this is to identify the cycles in this time series data and mark them as cycle1, cycle2..cyclen in the data file.

Comment: You'd be a lot happier, I suspect, using something like `pastecs:turnpoints` to find the actual peaks/valleys in your data.